# _NetUserAdd@16 cannot be resolved

Tags: c++, winapi, linker-errors

Im trying to add user via C++.I have to say I don't have any experience with VS and C++ at all. So I found out the function "NetUserAdd" and watched out for examples and build my own for it.But my Visual Studio gives me the first error:

> error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_NetUserAdd@16" in Funktion "_main".

It is in german and says that the symbol "_NetUserAdd@16" cannot be resolved.
Any Ideas ? I couldn't find the problem anywhere ...

```
 #ifdef _UNICODE
    typedef wchar_t TCHAR;
    #else
    typedef char TCHAR;
    #endif // _UNICODE

typedef const TCHAR* LPCTSTR;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <lm.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    USER_INFO_1 ui;
    DWORD dwLevel = 1;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    NET_API_STATUS nStatus;

    LPWSTR username = L"user";
    LPWSTR password = L"test234";

    ui.usri1_name = username;
    ui.usri1_password = password;
    ui.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_USER;
    ui.usri1_home_dir = NULL;
    ui.usri1_comment = NULL;
    ui.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT;
    ui.usri1_script_path = NULL;
    //
    // Call the NetUserAdd function, specifying level 1.
    //
    nStatus = NetUserAdd(NULL,
        dwLevel,
        (LPBYTE)&ui,
        &dwError);


    if (nStatus == NERR_Success)
        fwprintf(stderr, L"User %s has been successfully added on %s\n",
        username, NULL);
    //
    // Otherwise, print the system error.
    //
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "A system error has occurred: %d\n", nStatus);
    }


}
```

Comment: Just a pure guess: did you forget to link with any library?

Comment: Also, this does not look like `C` to me....

Comment: You need to link with either Netapi32.dll or Netapi32.lib

Comment: Did you check the [NetUserAdd Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? It tells you what libraries to link against.

Comment: Copy/paste this into your code: `#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370649.aspx) explains that you need to link with `Netapi32.lib`. It seems that you are failing to do this.